# How to convert my serverless.ts file to serverless.yaml file and make the serverless project work?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, serverless

I created a serverless project from a template aws-nodejs-typescript doing this:

```
sls create --template aws-nodejs-typescript --path my-app
```

However, it created for me a serverless.ts file instead of serverless.yaml.
I converted the serverless.yaml file to ts file.
However, I am stuck with some problems to make it work in my serverless configurations files.
Error after running: `sls deploy -v`

[image: Error after running: sls deploy -v]

Do someone knows how to fix it?
My project is in github:

[Github Serverless Project](https://github.com/MKortmann/10-udatype)

I would be very glad if someone can help me with this problem.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your setup, serverless is looking for configuration in `webpack.config.js`.

For `serverless-webpack` [plugin you can specify](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#configure) location/name of a config file:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    webpackConfig: 'webpack.config.ts'
```

You could also try to migrate your `webpack.config.ts` to `.js` with tsc transpiler `tsc --lib es6 webpack.config.ts`

Comment: Hello! I just added these lines of code to my serverless.yaml file and it worked!!! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

FYI: seems that configuration via .ts has been deprecated (moved to legacy; and removed from recent branches):

https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/22865199326008b9f863cb1ad28bfdddae9a7473/legacy/aws-nodejs-typescript/serverless.ts